# How to get rid of warning fold expressions only available with -std=c++17

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, c++17

I tired everything but I am still getting this warning when I am compiling my c++ code in Visual Studio Code.
`template<typename...T> void read(T&... args) {((cin>>args),...);}`

Here is the warning I am getting :
`warning: fold-expressions only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17 void read(T&... args) {((cin>>args),...);}`

The code running fine , but how can I fix this warning ?
I am using gcc version 8.1.0

I tried making changes with c_cpp_standard.json file by adding `"cppStandard": "gnu++17",` and `"cStandard": "c17",`, settings.json file , changes in task.json file by adding `-std=c++17` but nothing is working . It is still giving the same error

Comment: Can you please post the exact compilation command that is being executed? Not the JSON stuff, but the constructed command.